# Current location on job matches page is wrong

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

I was editing my match preferences for jobs and there is the checkbox to always include current location. However, that listed the last city I lived. I moved several months ago and updated my profile a while back with my new city location.

Comment: I think I remember something about that the location uses the IP location, not your location from your profile.  Not sure if that changed or not but if it didn't you may want to check the address of your IP.

Comment: Maybe, I'm vpn'd into my previous city location. But I also have another machine that is not vpn'd into that location. It seems like it would be better for it to prefer the location that is set in my profile or something. Oh well, I'll just leave it unchecked. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The home location in your match preferences comes from the location associated with your developer story (previously CV) and it falls back to your SO profile if you don't set it. I checked and the CV and match preferences are consistent.

You can also make sure that the two are synchronized by checking the 'Synchronize with profile' checkbox above the field on the developer story.

Comment: This is incorrect or broken. As jmoreno stated, it is unclear where to set current location. After updating the "Location" field on the "Edit Your Profile" page to a new location, checking the box "Always include your current location" (on the "Job match preferences" page) adds the old location (even after some time has passed since the change).

Comment: @deeprog this is not incorrect; change 'CV' for 'Developer Story' and it remains true. Your developer story is set to your previous location.

Comment: @deeprog I've updated my answer to take into account developer story but nothing really changes.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! You're absolutely right - I completely missed the developer story section. Answer upvoted.

Answer (score 1):

This problem still exists.  The developer story has gone live, the CV is no longer available, and Jobs/developer story shows my previous title and location.  When I go to edit match preference it shows my previous location.

Either this still exist, or I'm missing where I can set my current location.

**Update**: I was missing something.  To edit the location of your developer story from an iPad, you have to slect your profile picture, and then an edit button is displayed, which will let you change (or sync) your location.

Comment: Your developer story is set to your previous location and you haven't checked to synchronize your location with your profile...